# Unity 2D Sprites Pixel Imperfect in Game

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am trying to figure out a weird issue in Unity, where the sprites are not consistent. It seems like there is always a couple of pixels messed up every other or more columns, and it only appears to be like that in the game view. It doesn't look like that in the scene view. Here is one example....

This is the Game View, you can see for one a weird line in that one column of the rocks. And for the rocks it appears to happen like every 12 Columns. If you also look at the obsidian every column of obsidian looks different (very hard to tell but they are indeed different by a few pixels even tho they are the same sprite).

[image: This is the game view]

And here is the Scene view

[image: Scene View]

In the scene view they look perfect. And no differences.

What would cause this?

------ EDIT Below ------

Here is one of the terrain sprite sheets. I cut the sprite sheet into 32x32

[image]

And here is the main Camera.... If i change Projection from Perspective to Orthographic it gets even worse. The stone has that issue like every other stone

[image]

Here is an example of orthographic

[image]

And finally this is the settings for the layer that I put them on.

[image]

Comment: Just think about how do you draw a 10x10 picture onto a 11x10 canvas? There must be 1 col calculated.

Comment: what are texture import settings?

Comment: @Shingo I am not sure exactly what you mean.

Comment: @trollingchar I went ahead and updated post with the settings and more information

Comment: Interesting. The issue appears to go away if I change the display resolution to 1920x1080. Can someone explain exactly why none of the other display settings work? Most tutorials have the display to 16:10 and ill be honest i am very new to game development.